# How to remove/replace commit from closed pull request on Github

Tags: git, github

I saw similar threads here, but judging from the answers there, they are all dealing with open PRs. My case is a bit different.

I tried to make my first contribution to Github, I checked a few tutorials, forked, cloned, committed, pushed and created a PR.
Then I realized that I made commit with my primary email which I didn't want to expose. So I updated git config, ran `git commit --amend --author="new name <new@e.mail>"` and then force-pushed to the remote repo (fork).
But before that push I closed PR (guess that was a mistake).
And now, when I go to that PR I can see (by the commit hash) it still references the old commit and for some reason (Github policy) I can't reopen the PR because the branch was force-pushed.

Is there a solution for this?

EDIT: I was able to fetch my PR from original project by cloning it and adding `fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*` to `.git/gitconfig`.
But of course I can't push to it:
`git push origin pr/<pr_id>`
gives error:
`remote: Permission to original/project.git denied to <username>.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/original/project.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found a solution. :)
First, short summary of the problem:
1) PR is closed and that is the reason why it is not being updated automatically from fork repo;
2) PR can't be reopened because fork repo has been force-pushed.

Now, to solve the problem:

1. Clone fixed fork repo.
2. Delete fix commit. For me it was simple: `git reset --hard HEAD~1`. Now the branch is in the original state - without changes for PR.
3. Get PR branch from original repo to local fork repo. I already fetched that repo with all PRs locally, so I added local remote: `git remote add localorigin ..\<original_repo>\` and then `git checkout --track localorigin/pr/<id>`. Check that this is the correct PR.
4. Checkout working branch and merge 'old' PR `git merge pr/<id>`. Now local fork repo has the wrong commit in it.
5. Force-push fork.
6. Reopen PR (now PR can be reopened, because the 'original PR branch' has been restored in the fork repo.
7. Go to fork repo and apply the fix. For me it was `git commit --amend --author="new_name <new@e.mail>"`.
8. Force-push fork again. Now fix appears in remote fork repo and because PR is open, the changes are automatically copied to the original repo's PR branch.

Answer (score 0):

A PR is just a wrapper around a branch - so when you made the PR there was a branch associated with it. If you modify the branch, then the PR will also be modified.

Say the branch was called `new_pr` you can do:

```
# Checkout the branch
git checkout new_pr

# Make sure your default email address is correct
git config --global user.email you@example.com

# Change any commits to remove email, i.e.:
git commit --amend --reset-author
# (or if it's wrong for several commits, use 'rebase')

# force push this branch over the 'wrong' one on github
git push origin new_pr --force
```

Now the github branch will have the correct email address in it, and the PR, if acessible, will 'auto-update' to point to the contents of the updated branch.

Comment: As you can see from initial post, I already modified the branch and pushed it (with --force option) to Github. The branch on Github is already updated: old commit has been replaced with the new one. But old commit was 'copied' to PR branch in the original project, and that PR branch still has old commit. No 'auto-update' has happened. I added more details to the initial question.